# cannot send ejs file through nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

it shows this error
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Promise

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       service: "gmail",
       auth:{
            user:process.env.email,
            pass: process.env.password
       }

  })
      
  
       
      const mailOptions = {
           from:process.env.email,
           to : req.user.username,
           subject:"Test",
           html: ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname,'views/home.ejs'))
           
           
           
        }
       
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,info){
             if(err){
                  console.log("err");
             }
             else{
                  console.log("sent" +info.response);
             }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

`ejs.renderFile` is asynchronous, use a callback to fetch the rendered HTML

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "gmail",
auth: {
    user: process.env.email,
    pass: process.env.password
}

})
const mailOptions = {
from: process.env.email,
to: req.user.username,
subject: "Test"

}
ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/home.ejs'), { name: name }, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    mailOptions.html = data
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err");
        }
        else {
            console.log("sent" + info.response);
        }
    })
}
});
```

Or Using `Asyn/Await`

```
export default async (nodemailer) => {
try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.email,
            pass: process.env.password
        }
    })
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.email,
        to: req.user.username,
        subject: "Test"
    }

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/home.ejs'), { name }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
             resolve(data)                
        });
    })

    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, error => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve('Email sent');
        });
    });
    console.log(response);
    return response

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}
```